# Issues when OUTER JOIN three different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Good morning everyone.

**CONTEXT**
I am in this situation: I have three tables structured this way (omitting ids for brevity)

SUBS: code, mag, start, end
USERS: code, email
ISSUES: issue, mag, pubdate

"subs" contains subscriptions to magazines: CODE is the company code, MAG is the identifier of the mag, START and END are the dates on which the subscription is valid.
"users" contains emails associated with the company codes (1/N)
"issues" is a list of each issue of each magazine, with its publication date

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
SUBS: C0003072, 01ARS, 2014-01-01, 2014-03-01  
ISSUES: 01ARS14000387, 01ARS, 2014-01-01  
        01ARS14000388, 01ARS, 2014-02-01
        01ARS14000389, 01ARS, 2014-03-01
        01ARS14000390, 01ARS, 2014-04-01  
USERS: C0003072, johndoe@mail.com  
       C0003072, laracroft@mail.com
```

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**
A list of all the users with the magazines they're entitled to see. If there are no magazines in their sub, i just need the user. So, for the example before:

```
johndoe@mail.com, 01ARS14000387
johndoe@mail.com, 01ARS14000388
johndoe@mail.com, 01ARS14000389
laracroft@mail.com, 01ARS14000387
laracroft@mail.com, 01ARS14000388
laracroft@mail.com, 01ARS14000389
```

**WHERE I AM STUCK**
I have written two distinct queries:

```
SELECT subs.code, issues.issue
FROM subs
LEFT JOIN issues
ON subs.mag=issues.mag
WHERE issues.pubdate<=subs.end
AND issues.pubdate>=subs.start
```

This correctly gives me the list of *all the magazines a company should see*
The following step is where I have problems at. I try to put together a single query to obtain the aforementioned desired result, but I keep getting a syntax error I don't understand. This is my query:

```
SELECT subs.code, issues.issue, users.email
FROM subs
LEFT JOIN issues
ON subs.mag=issues.mag
OUTER JOIN users
ON subs.code=users.code
WHERE issues.pubdate<=subs.end
AND issues.pubdate>=subs.start
```

To my, albeit limited, knowledge of sql I need to use the outer join to get EACH user, even if they have no magazines. But this doesn't seem to work

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No one will help you until you provide scripts, at first read [this article](http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html)

Comment: Since you want all users, `users` should be the `FROM` table, and you should then `LEFT JOIN` with the other two tables.

Comment: @zaratustra thanks for that link, that's pretty useful. Sorry if my post was badly written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary table for your query should be `users`. Then you `LEFT JOIN` the other two tables, since those are the ones that may not have matches.

```
SELECT users.email, subs.code, issues.issue
FROM users
LEFT JOIN subs ON users.code = subs.code
LEFT JOIN issues ON subs.mag = issues.mag AND issues.pubdate BETWEEN subs.start AND subs.end
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15c003/1)

Comment: To clarify, if I'm getting this correctly, this at the moment returns me a list of all the users which have a sub, but NOT the complete list of users. I need the latter. Am I missing something again?

Comment: It's working for me. See the demo. It returns all the users. For laracroft, `code` and `issue` are null because her code doesn't match any subs. For foo, `issue` is null because none of the issues are within the start-end range of the sub.

Comment: I saw your fiddle, thanks a lot. It works for NULL code values too, which is my case.

Answer (score 0):

The last query missies the outer join type (left or right):

So the correct query will be:

```
SELECT subs.code, issues.issue, users.email
FROM subs
LEFT JOIN issues
ON subs.mag=issues.mag
LEFT JOIN users
ON subs.code=users.code
WHERE issues.pubdate<=subs.end
AND issues.pubdate>=subs.start
```